# Get escaped " (&quote;) and ' (&apos;) chars in xml output after xsl transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, xslt-1.0

I need to escape `"` and `'` in an xml file to `&quot;` `&apos;` using XSLT 1.0 due to that the consuming system cannot handle these characters inside an xml element.

I've run into two issues that I haven't solved.

1. Being able to match `'` at all.
2. Getting my `&quot;` to stay escaped (while not ruining the whole string).

I'm now believing this cannot be done. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>
      <att name="name">Let's fix these "errors".</att>
   </bar>
</foo>
```

Wanted output would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>
      <att name="name">Let&apos;s fix these &quot;errors&quot;.</att>
   </bar>
</foo>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="att[@name ='name']">
        <xsl:param name="content" select="text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="replaceApos">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$content" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#39;'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'&apos;'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="replaceQuot">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$replaceApos" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'&amp;quot;'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <att name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$replaceQuot"/></att>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" />
        <xsl:param name="by" />
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$text = '' or $replace = ''or not($replace)" > 
                <!-- Prevent this routine from hanging -->
                       <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(note: above XSL won't validate with `'&#39;` or `&apos;`)

Q1. Regardless if I use `&apos;` `&#39;` or `&#x0027;` my validator complains and won't allow matching. Any way around this? Is this expected?

Q2. If I skip apos and only focus on the `"`: If I use `by` as `&quot;` i get `"` in the output.
If I use `by` as `&amp;quot;` I get `&amp;quot;`in the output and not only `&quot;`

In my validator I can see that the variable `replaceQuot`is correct, i.e. `Let's fix these &quot;errors&quot;` but the xml output is not "correct".

If I use `<att name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$replaceQuot" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></att>` then everything is as is. (I get expected, wanted text), But which makes this solution impossible is that the I also could have `<` `&` and `>` in this field, which I need to have escaped (I need valid xml).

Is there any way to mitigate? character-maps which I guess could solve this is only available from 2.0 as I understand it.

My take on this is that this is impossible to manage with xslt 1.0, and I need to either push consuming system to fix their import functionality or solve it in a post xml-step by another tool. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the target system would of course be the preferable solution.

Still, assuming that your processor supports `disable-output-escaping`, you should be able to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="att[@name='name']/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="escape-apos">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="searchString">'</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="replaceString">&amp;apos;</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="escape-quotes">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$escape-apos"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="searchString">"</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="replaceString">&amp;quot;</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$escape-quotes" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchString"/>
    <xsl:param name="replaceString"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$searchString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$searchString)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replaceString"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$searchString)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$replaceString"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this may seriously backfire if the text contains characters that should **not** be unescaped - for example, an actual ampersand.

---

### Added:

Here's a sketch of an approach that could work with text that contains characters like `&amp;` or `&lt;` that need to remain escaped:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="att[@name ='name']/text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="process">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $apos) or contains($text, $quot)">
            <xsl:variable name="bef-apos" select="substring-before($text, $apos)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="bef-quot" select="substring-before($text, $quot)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$bef-apos and (not($bef-quot) or string-length($bef-apos) &lt; string-length($bef-quot))">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$bef-apos"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;apos;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:call-template name="process">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $apos)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$bef-quot"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:call-template name="process">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $quot)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Caveat**: not tested very thoroughly. Could probably be made more elegant with more work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get ampersands, < and > in this name field occasionally, so I cannot use disable-output-escaping=yes.

Comment: Didn't even think of trying out <xsl:with-param name="searchString">'</xsl:with-param> instead of using the select. Solves my Q1 flawlessly.

Comment: Well, I believe there is a way around that, but it is an awful lot of work. Basically, you need to have the processing template write directly to the output. That means you cannot do the replacements in two passes; you need to check if the next character is `'` or `"` and select the one that comes first. Then you can use `disable-output-escaping` only when outputting the replacement string itself.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work...  I'll see if I can push for consuming system fix. This will handle lots and lots of files, so needs something that doesn't take too much computing also.  Maybe then should check if I also have <, & and > in the field, and if not, do the disable-output-escaping, otherwise I need to implement your idea.

Comment: Brilliant! It works when testing briefly here. Need some time to grasp what you've actually manage to craft there.